# Looking for a way to calculate time lapse in openrefine

Tags: date, diff, data-cleaning, openrefine, grel

This is the given expression of GREL language on OpenRefine.

diff(date d1, date d2, optional string timeUnit)

For dates, returns the difference in given time units.

So the question is how to get the access to the values of both columns, that is not clear on presented on the documentation.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The formula for accessing another column is:

```
cells.YourColumnName.value
```

If your column name contains spaces or non-ascii characters :

```
cells['Your Column Name'].value
```

So, assuming your two columns are named "date1" and "date2", and you want the difference in days, the GREL formula is as follows :

```
diff(cells.date1.value, cells.date2.value, "days")
```

or

```
diff(cells['date1'].value, cells['date2'].value, "days")
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a way myself here is the example of the working command, the GREL documentation is not that explicit treating this procedure.

Here is the commend I used, I multiplied the result by -1 to make it positive.

```
diff(cells["DATA_COMPRA"].value, cells["DATA_VENCIMENTO"].value, "days") * -1
```

Hope that helps, I my have to come back here sometimes to get this script again and again.

Comment: [I've just updated the documentation.](https://github.com/OpenRefine/OpenRefine/wiki/GREL-Date-Functions) Open Refine is an open source project run by its user community,  including you. :) Do not hesitate to complete the doc when you find it too vague.

Comment: Super thanks Ettore, as I am new to the stack overflow, git and all this, I didn´t think I could change something out there. Thanks for sending me the link, now I can see the edit button. Sure I will contribute, I have got so much already from the community. The tool is helping lots of students here to improve their data quality.